# Better debug output

Tags: debugging

I'd like to know if there is any way to output the document's source before any of it is rendered. This would mean retaining all tags, markup, and code: PHP, HTML, EE tags, scripts, etc to see the entire doc. All this set is accessible via debug but it's horrendously garbled and hard to shift through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not following your question 100% but take a look at the [**EE Debug Toolbar**](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ee-debug-toolbar). It's the newest addon for debugging EE templates and may give you more of what you're wanting.

> Adds an unobtrusive interface for debugging output on an
>   ExpressionEngine 2.0 site. Replaces default Profiler and Template
>   Debugger provided with ExpressionEngine.